# Can't connect to Exchange 2016 server via PowerShell from CentOS

Tags: powershell, centos, exchange-server, exchange-server-2016

Need to connect to the Exchange 2016 server via PowerShell from CentOS. When connecting from Windows, I used the following:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://*******/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential (Get-Credential) 
Import-PSSession $Session
```

It doesn't work out of CentOS. I tried all possible authentication options.

```
Credentials:
User: DOMAIN\USER
Password: PASSWORD

Error:
New-PSSession: Connecting to remote server ****** failed with the following error message : Kerberos verify cred with password failed No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```